# Conditionally activate Gesture in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, gesture

I'm looking for a way to able/disable DragGesture or to pass conditionally pass the Gesture to MyView() in swiftUI according to @State private var isDraggable:Bool

Since MyView() has some parameters that are reset on Appear() and Disappear(), I can not just do

```
If isDraggable { MyView() }else{MyView().gesture() }
```

How DragGesture is implemented in my code

```
MyView().gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0) .onChanged { value in} )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GestureMask` and choose between gestures

you can have .all, .none, .subviews, or .gesture

`.gesture` in your case would be the `DragGesture`.

`.subviews` would allow any gestures inside `MyView`

`.all` is both the `DragGesture` AND any gestures inside `MyView` (this is the default)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ConditionalGestureView: View {
    @State var activeGestures: GestureMask = .subviews
    var body: some View {
        MyView()
            .gesture(DragGesture(), including: activeGestures)
    }
}
```

Change the `activeGestures` variable per your use case

Comment: I had come up with a transparent layer to catch Gestures (that was working also) but this solution is  much more elegant and advanced  , Thanx !