# SwiftUI AVPlayer with Parent onTapGesture

Tags: swift, swiftui, avplayer

I have a list of cells that may contain an AVPlayer for video url, the issue is that the AVPlayer is not usable because there is an onTapGesture in the parent view that presents the cell in full screen on tap, but I want the AVPlayer to be usable without having to present the full screen.

How can I allow users to play/pause/rewind/fast forward with a parent on tap gesture?

This is a simple version of the code structure:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0...4, id: \.self) { _ in
            PlayerView()
                .onTapGesture {
                    // Present full screen
                }
        }
    }
}

struct PlayerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(URL(string: "https://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html")))
    }
}
```

I've tried using

`.allowsHitTesting(false)`

on the AVPlayer, but that did not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71469248/conditionnaly-activate-gesture-in-swiftui/71469778#71469778

Comment: @loremipsum not helpful

Comment: I noticed that, if you do a longer press (eg 0.2 sec), not just a quick tap, the code actually works for me. The `.onTapGesture{..}` is triggered and the player can be activated.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine do you have any code to show?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used for testing. On MacOS 13.4, using Xcode 14.3, tested on real ios 16 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst. Press the `play` button for a bit longer than normal, and the
movie will start with the control accessible. Even with the controls, press a bit longer than just a quick tap and the app works for me.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0...1, id: \.self) { _ in
            PlayerView()
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("---> ContentView onTapGesture")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct PlayerView: View {
    private let player = AVPlayer(url:  URL(string: "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4")!)

    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
    }
}
```