UIHostingController blocking touch events to underlying UIHostingController
I have a very simplified version below of some code I'm trying to make work.
Code explained:

ContentView1 - a SwiftUI view with a button and counter label
ContentView2 - a VStack with text at the bottom and whitespace at
the top
ViewController - a standard UIKit view controller that
embeds each of these views into its own hosting controller and
overlays ContentView2 on ContentView1.

Here is the code:
ContentView1
struct ContentView1: View {
    
    @State var count = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Text("\(count)")
            Button(
                action: {
                    count += 1
                },
                label: {
                    Text("Increase")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

ContentView2
struct ContentView2: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Hello world")
        }
    }
}

ViewController
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Add ContentView1
        let view1 = ContentView1()
        let hosting1 = UIHostingController(rootView: view1)
        hosting1.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addChild(hosting1)
        self.view.addSubview(hosting1.view)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            hosting1.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            hosting1.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
            hosting1.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            hosting1.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
        
        // Add ContentView2
        let view2 = ContentView2()
        let hosting2 = UIHostingController(rootView: view2)
        hosting2.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hosting2.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.addChild(hosting2)
        self.view.addSubview(hosting2.view)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            hosting2.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            hosting2.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
            hosting2.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            hosting2.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

The issue
The button in ContentView1 does not work, and I cannot seem to find a way to not have the touch event passed from ContentView2 -> ContentView1.
Things I have considered:

You will notice I've already added hosting2.view.backgroundColor = .clear - ContentView1 is visible, just not tappable.
It is not an option to make hosting2.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false because I want some interaction with it (not included in simplified snippet).
I cannot re-write this to be a single SwiftUI view inside a ZStack - remember this is a simplified version of some production code that I can't easily rejig that way.

Finally, I have tried the following solution:

Implement a custom PassthroughView that inherits from UIView and implements override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
Create a PassthroughHostingController and override loadView setting the custom passthrough view

But this is even worse - the SwiftUI view won't even load with this solution.
How to resolve this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71469248/conditionally-activate-gesture-in-swiftui/71469778#71469778

Sorry @loremipsum I don't follow - how does this resolve the issue?

An idea of how to apply conditional gestures. It isn’t an answer just something that might lead you to an answer.

@loremipsum I just can't see how - the issue is that the responder chain isn't working as I'd expect it to. I can't conditionally listen for gestures if no gestures at all get passed from the top view to the one beneath.

Ok then disregard it was just a comment.

@loremipsum np just wanted to make sure I understood

Short Explanation
What happened there is that ContentView2 fills all the area vertically and is placed over the ContentView1. Because of that, ContentView2 is blocking the ContentView1's touch interaction.
Debugging Process
If you add background to the ContentViews that you provided (ContentView1 — red, ContentView2 — blue with 0.5 opacity), you will see that ContentView2 touches the top and covers the ContentView1, which is placed under the ContentView2. And because it covers the ContentView1, we don't have access to it, and we can't interact with it. In the code provided in the question, it's not visible, because the background is clear — so adding the background shows how the view is actually rendered.

Problematic Code
The reason it happens is that you have this code:
self.view.addSubview(hosting2.view)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    hosting2.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor), // << Here
    hosting2.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
    // ...
])

Solutions
You have a few options:

Set a height anchor using the constant: hosting2.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100) (personally, I wouldn't recommend that, but it solves the issue).
Replace hosting2.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor) with hosting2.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hosting1.view.bottomAnchor). Thanks to this change, you will set the top anchor of hosting2 to the bottom anchor of the hosting1 view, so it will be placed below the hosting1 instead of being placed below it (so none of the views will be covered by the other one).

